# Check validations about Personalausweis data

Tags: php, validation

The validations for german ID document are not working anymore according to this:

https://www.php-einfach.de/diverses/personalausweis-ueberpruefen/?check=1 The main function in PHP code is as below:

```
//Pruefnummer ueberpruefen
function check_number($id, $checknumber) {
$p = 7;
$sum = 0;
for($i=0; $i < strlen($id); $i++) {
$char = $id{$i};

if($char >= '0' && $char <= '9')
$int = intval($char);
else
$int = ord($char)-55;

$sum += $int*$p;

if($p==1)
$p=7;
else if($p==3)
$p=1;
else if($p==7)
$p=3;
}

$last_number = substr(strval($sum), -1);

return $last_number == $checknumber;
}
```

Is there any solutions about validation Personalausweis datain german ID document? This is the link that displays the ID card: https://www.personalausweisportal.de/Webs/PA/EN/citizens/german-id-card/data-on-the-id-card/data-on-the-id-card-node.html

Comment: I don't see any indication in any of the links above that it should not work. Does it work for you? If it doesn't, what is it you do to test it, what happens, what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I tested the above examples to the testing site and it is not working. I excepted the message "Personalausweis nummer is correct"

Comment: Well, the examples might be wrong. They weren't made by the testing site and the people posting them probably did not care enough (or knew enough math) to get the check digit right. Hint: it must be 6 instead of 9 in the end.

Comment: The examples are correct and I think I found a solution. It seems to be working now.